# This is my query. i want to get latest recored from groupby date and user_id

Tags: php, laravel

```
`$query = IpDetails::with('user', 'user.subUser')->select('*', \DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'))->where('is_login', true)->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate)->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate)->where('from', 'user')->when($status != 'all',function($q) use ($status){$q->whereHas('user.subUser',function($q) use ($status){$q->where('is_active',$status);});})->groupBy('user_id', 'date');`
```

this is my query.its getting first record not latest

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = IpDetails::with('user', 'user.subUser')
    ->select('*', \DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'))
    ->where('is_login', true)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate)
    ->where('from', 'user')
    ->when($status != 'all', function($q) use ($status) {
        $q->whereHas('user.subUser', function($q) use ($status) {
            $q->where('is_active', $status);
        });
    })
    ->groupBy('user_id', 'date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'desc')  // Add this line to order by date in descending order
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');  // If there are records with the same date, order by created_at in descending order
```